# Use of NetworkHash128 assetId in Custom Spawn Handler

Tags: unity, unity-networking

I was learning Custom spawn handler on [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetCustomSpawning.html). It says before spawning we need to Register Spawn handler using `ClientScene.RegisterSpawnHandler(coinAssetId, SpawnCoin, UnSpawnCoin);`
 I understood SpawnCoin and UnSpawnCoin is Handler function that will be invoked on clients but what is the use of `coinAssetId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answered on Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/question-on-unity-custom-spawn-handler.602182/#post-4030528) Answered by @goldbug [Goldbug](https://forum.unity.com/members/goldbug.67860/) from Unity Forum